# How to get json data X times using *ngFor

Tags: html, angular

I want to get 3 images from my endpoint which has lots of images using angular *ngFor(or any other available approach)

Here's my component.html

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6" *ngFor="let result of data.response.constructor(3)">
  <div class="panel-thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive"  width="200" [src]="result.thumbnail"></div>
 </div>
```

Ts file

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
public data:any = []
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
getData(){
  const url ='myUrl'
this.http.get(url).subscribe((res)=>{
  this.data = res
  console.log(this.data)
})}
ngOnInit(): void {
 this.getData()}}
```

I've try to use the [].constructor(3) as suggested from other posts but i dont get any result.
Can someone help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use slice to get an array with expected number of item

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6" *ngFor="let result of data.response.slice(0,3)">
  <div class="panel-thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive"  width="200" [src]="result.thumbnail"></div>
 </div>
```

syntax is

```
array.slice(first, numberOfElement)
```